# Displaying an Android ListView right arrow, to indicate that there is more to see

Tags: android, listview

I was just curious if there was an easy way to display a right arrow on rows in a ListView (similar to the way iPhone does it)? Or is it only doable manually by sticking an ImageView with an arrow (aligned to the right)?

Comment: as far as i know yes you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ended up doing it manually with an ImageView.